# Trick when update null column

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have following query to update column with previous value 
where column is null:

```
UPDATE day_status a 
SET a.ch_size = 
( 
  SELECT LAG(ch_size) OVER (ORDER BY item, daytime) as prev_choke
  FROM day_status b
  WHERE a.item = b.item AND a.daytime=b.daytime
) 
WHERE a.ch_size IS NULL AND a.sub_hours = 0.5
```

But for some reason it sets to null while there is previous value, see example below:

```
Item daytime               sub_hours  ch_size prev_choke
 -------------------------------------------------------
 t23  18-Aug-17 03:30:00    0.5        56.8   
 t23  18-Aug-17 04:00:00    0.5               56.8
 t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.5        40.8
 t24  18-Aug-17 04:40:00    0.5               40.8  
 t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0          45.4
```

this is how table looks like:

```
 Item daytime               sub_hours  ch_size
  -------------------------------------------------------
  t23  18-Aug-17 03:30:00    0.5        56.8
  t23  18-Aug-17 04:00:00    0.5  
  t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.5        40.8
  t24  18-Aug-17 04:40:00    0.5           
  t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0          45.4
  t23  19-Aug-17 03:30:00    0.5        70.2
  t23  19-Aug-17 04:00:00    0.5  
  t24  19-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.5        40.8
  t24  19-Aug-17 04:40:00    0.5           
  t24  19-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.2
```

this how table should look like after update:

```
 Item daytime               sub_hours  ch_size
  -------------------------------------------------------
  t23  18-Aug-17 03:30:00    0.5        56.8
  t23  18-Aug-17 04:00:00    0.5        56.8
  t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.5        40.8
  t24  18-Aug-17 04:40:00    0.5        40.8  
  t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0          45.4
  t23  19-Aug-17 03:30:00    0.5        70.2
  t23  19-Aug-17 04:00:00    0.5        70.2
  t24  19-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.5        40.8
  t24  19-Aug-17 04:40:00    0.5        40.8       
  t24  19-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.2
```

Where could be a trick?

Comment: please add how the table Looks before the `UPDATE` and how you **want** it to look after

Comment: to RealCheeseLord: added

Answer (score 3):

The `lag()` is calculated *after* the `where` clause.  So, you can do:

```
UPDATE day_status ds
    SET ch_size = (SELECT prev_choke
                   FROM (SELECT d2.*,
                                LAG(ch_size) OVER (ORDER BY item, daytime) as prev_choke
                         FROM day_status ds2
                        ) ds2
                   WHERE ds.item = ds2.item AND ds.daytime = ds2.daytime
                  ) 
WHERE a.ch_size IS NULL AND a.sub_hours = 0.5;
```

I would also assume that you intend `partition by item order by daytime`.

EDIT:

Strictly speaking, you could add:

```
UPDATE day_status ds
    SET ch_size = (SELECT prev_choke
                   FROM (SELECT d2.*,
                                LAG(ch_size) OVER (ORDER BY item, daytime) as prev_choke
                         FROM day_status ds2
                        ) ds2
                   WHERE ds.item = ds2.item AND ds.daytime = ds2.daytime
                  ) 
WHERE a.ch_size IS NULL AND a.sub_hours = 0.5 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT prev_choke
              FROM (SELECT d2.*,
                           LAG(ch_size) OVER (ORDER BY item, daytime) as prev_choke
                    FROM day_status ds2
                   ) ds2
              WHERE ds.item = ds2.item AND ds.daytime = ds2.daytime AND
                    prev_choke IS NOT NULL
             ) ;
```

However, you might want to take a different approach, such as using `merge`.

Comment: to Gordon Linoff: Thanks, let me test it, one moment

Comment: thanks Gordon Linoff: it works perfect, can I add one more condition, in "WHERE a.ch_size IS NULL AND a.sub_hours = 0.5", I'd like to add where previous value is not null also, how I could do that, I believe we can't add LAG function to where clause?

Comment: @JoeGreen . . . I'm not sure where you want the condition.  It would either go in the `where` clause for the subquery or in a new `where` clause in the outer query.